# want to use block of code in all method of particular class

Tags: oop, spring-mvc

We are using Spring MVC, in that for one particular module one controller class is their and for different pages of that module we have different method in the same class.

Every thing works fine but we want some code (i.e. for page history and other logs) to use in all methods. Currently we are copy pasting that code in all methods but want some good solution that we reuse the code block.

Comment: Create a Utils class and try use reuse that code

Answer (score 0):

Write a static method in under a class name Utils and use it everywhere

```
Utils.method();
```